# Tracking player health text based game - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a hard time tracking and adjusting `player["health"]` I created a function `reduce_health():` that lowers the player health based on enemy attack, but when I run a fight the health does not work. I just simply win the fight or when I edit the code it just goes back and forth attacking forever. How can I create a function the reduce health and tracks it after each attack until the player dies? Note the code may not look well structured because I'm still working on it and will clean it up after I figure this out.

```
import random
import time

#Tracking weapon and player health
player = {"weapon":None, "health": None}

#function for questions avoide repeat 
def ask(question):
    answer = input(question + " [y/n]")
    return answer in ["y", "Y", "Yes", "YES", "yes"]

def game_over():
  print ("You Lose")
#initial question to start
print ("The adventures Of Magical Nadia")

#Question to start game or end game
if ask("Do you wish to embark on this great adventure?"):
  print ("You have accepted the adventure. God Speed my young rass!")
  player["health"] = 100
else:
  print ("You are a coward and shall not in bark on a great adventure!")

#Dic of all the weapons in the game
WEAPONS = {
  "Spear": (3, 10), None:(1,3), "knife":(4,16), "Gun":(16,25), "Glass Bottle":(4,16)
}


#to give the player weapons code
#player["weapon"] = "Spear"


#Enemys type
enemy = {"name":None, "health":None, "attack":None }
Gaint_spider = {"name":"Spider","health":(10), "attack":(7, 10) } 
Dogs = {"name":"Dogs","health": (50), "attack":(4,15)}
Dragon = {"name":"Dragon","health": (150), "attack":(35,45)}

def reduce_health():
  healthcheck = int(player["health"])
  enemyattack = int("enemy_damage")
  player["health"] = healthcheck - enemyattack
  print (player["health"])
  if player["health"] <= 0:
    game_over()
#Function each fight gives random dmg, have a player and enemy, winner and loser

def combat (player, enemy):
    player_damage = random.randint (*WEAPONS[player["weapon"]])
    enemy_damage = random.randint(*enemy["attack"])
    player_win = player_damage >= enemy["health"]
    enemy_win= enemy_damage  >= player["health"]

    return player_damage, player_win , enemy_damage, enemy_win


#Structure of a fight 
Sample_FIGHT = {
"player_damage": "You desperately try to stop the %s for %i damage",
"enemy_damage": "%s gores you for %i damage",
"player_win": "The %s collapses with a thunderous boom",
"enemy_win": "You are squished"
}

# describe the fight in a function

def describe_combat(player, enemy, fight_description,reduce_health):
   player_damage, player_win , enemy_damage, enemy_win = combat(player, enemy)

   print (fight_description["player_damage"] % (enemy["name"], player_damage))
   time.sleep(1.0) 
   print (fight_description["enemy_damage"] % (enemy["name"], enemy_damage) )
   return reduce_health

   if player_win:
      print (fight_description["player_win"] % enemy["name"])
      return True

   if enemy_win:
      print (fight_description["player_win"] % enemy["name"])
      return False

      return None # fight is a draw

fight_result = describe_combat(player, Gaint_spider, Sample_FIGHT, reduce_health)
while fight_result is None:
   describe_combat(player, Gaint_spider, Sample_FIGHT,reduce_health)
if True: 
   print ("You have won the fight")
else:
   print ("You lost")
```

Returns this:

```
The adventures Of Magical Nadia
Do you wish to embark on this great adventure? [y/n] Y
You have accepted the adventure. God Speed my young rass!
You desperately try to stop the Spider for 2 damage
Spider gores you for 7 damage
You have won the fight
```

Goal:

```
The adventures Of Magical Nadia
Do you wish to embark on this great adventure? [y/n] Y
You have accepted the adventure. God Speed my young rass!
You desperately try to stop the Spider for 2 damage
Spider gores you for 7 damage
Player health 93
You desperately try to stop the Spider for 2 damage
Spider gores you for 7 damage
Player health 86
```

Comment: What does this mean: `int("enemy_damage")`

Comment: you are returning early with `return reduce_health`, also `return None` is badly indented. You are never reaching that line in your method. Also, `fight_result` has the value of `reduce_health`, and is not changing inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a dict to store player attributes, why not use a class?

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, weapon, health):
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.health = health

    def reduce_health(amount):
        self.health -= amount
```

You can add additional methods like `calculate_damage()` to the `Player` class that take into account the type of weapon the player has. If you also create a monster class, your fight sequence could look something like

```
def fight():
    monster.reduce_health(player.calculate_damage())
    monster.check_dead()
    player.reduce_health(monster.calculate_damage())
    player.check_dead()
    ...
```

Comment: I was trying to not use classes because I plan to rebuild this project using classes and so on because it's cleaner code. This is my second project learning python.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense. I'm going to start using classes.

Comment: After you finish an implementation with classes, you could head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask for critique.